# Create a Blob from a Base64 string

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I am unsuccessfully trying to create a blob from an base64 string.

The variable `base64` has an image(encoded in base64).

```
var blob = new Blob([window.atob(base64)], {type : 'image/png'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I have created the following jsfiddle as well

http://jsfiddle.net/83PQs/6/